# Knapsack problem in R: How to use loop in R to check for each item instead of whole column

Tags: r, knapsack-problem

I've been taking a "Simulation" course in my uni and now have a task to solve a knapsack problem.
Basically I have 3 transporters (g1, g2, g3) which each can carry different weights, on top of that you can put each item 5 times in a transporter. My idea is to use a while loop so it would run as long as the total weight is below the maximum weight. And that the program would pick the item with the highest relation first as long as their pick index doesnt equal 0.
But here I got stuck, it seems that it takes all items of the column at once per loop and also doesnt stop when the value exceeds the maximum (it returns weight = 748 at the end).

Hence: how do I get the loop to just check per item and not the whole column and how can I ensure that it doesnt exceed the weight limit?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!!

````
WeightIndex<- c(2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 8, 15, 9, 11) #indexing the weight of each item
WorthIndex <-c(3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 3, 21, 11, 10)#indexing the worth of each item
Relation <- WorthIndex/WeightIndex #creates a relation between weight/worth of the item
PickIndex <- rep(5,10) #each item can be picked 5 times


Items <-cbind(ItemIndex, WeightIndex, WorthIndex, Relation, PickIndex) #binding the indexes to a matrix


g1 <- 300 #Max weight of carrier 1
g2 <- 250 #max weight of carrier 2
g3 <- 200 #max weight of carrier 3

ItemsSorted<-Items[order(Items[,4],decreasing=TRUE),] #Sorts the items after the highest Relation of weight to worth

ItemsSorted1 <- ItemsSorted #creates a copied matrix for the first loop

TWE1 <-0#Total Weight  of carrier 1

TWO1 <-0 #total worth  of carrier 1


print (ItemsSorted1) #bug check

while (TWE1 <= g1){    #while the condition is true, the program should execute a for loop
  

    if(ItemsSorted1[,5]!= 0) #in theory the loop should go bottom down and take the items with the highest price/weight relation first and it should only take items whose pick-index doesnt equal 0
      {  
   TWE1<-TWE1+ItemsSorted1[,2] #the weight of the taken item gets appended to the list of the total weight
   TWO1 <-TWO1 + ItemsSorted1[,3] #the worth of the taken item gets appended to the list of total worth
    ItemsSorted1[,5] <- ItemsSorted1[,5] - 1 #deducts 1 from the pick- Index as the item has been taken
    TWE1 <- sum(TWE1) #turns the list into one number
    TWO1 <- sum(TWO1) #turns the list into one number
    print(TWE1)    #bug check
    }
  
}


print(paste("Total weight C1",TWE1))
print(paste("Total worth C1",TWO1))
print(ItemsSorted1)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skimming your code, it looks like you're missing some way to index which number you're referencing in the `ItemsSorted1` matrix. Your comment after the `while` statement says you're expecting the code to run a for-loop, but as written, it doesn't have a variable to increment.

You might be able to do something like the following to get at your expected behavior:

```
i <- 1 # create row-id variable to keep track of position in ItemsSorted1

while (TWE1 <= g1){    
   if(ItemsSorted1[i,5]!= 0){ # go item by item through the sorted list;
      TWE1<-TWE1+ItemsSorted1[i,2] #the weight of the taken item gets appended to the list of the total weight
      TWO1 <-TWO1 + ItemsSorted1[i,3] #the worth of the taken item gets appended to the list of total worth
      ItemsSorted1[i,5] <- ItemsSorted1[i,5] - 1 #deducts 1 from the pick- Index as the item has been taken
      TWE1 <- sum(TWE1) #turns the list into one number
      TWO1 <- sum(TWO1) #turns the list into one number
      print(TWE1)    #bug check
   }
   else if (i<nrow(ItemsSorted1){
      i <- i+1 
   }else{
      break
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've just tried your solution out and it just works like I've wanted it to! Thank you so much!! I'll make sure to read up more on indexing in programming so I can understand and apply it better :) 
thanks again and have a nice day/night!

Comment: Glad to help! If this solution worked for you, can you select my response as the answer (click the checkmark)?